# Linq 2 SQL multiple joins to a table

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have inherited a web app and in the process of updating. Part of my updates involve changing SQL scripts in Linq statement. Most are simple enough but I've come to a full stop with one particular script.

```
    SELECT ID, DateRecd, b.FullName As RecdBy, OrderID, c.ProductType, a.ProductRef, 
c.ProdName, c.ProdCat, Qty FROM tblOrderData As a 
JOIN tblUsers As n ON a.RecdBy = n.UserNo 
JOIN tblProducts As c ON a.ProductRef = c.ProductRef 
WHERE a.ProductRef LIKE '" & tb_ProdRefFind.Text.Trim() & "%' AND DateProcessed Is Null

Dim Orders2Process = (From od In dc.tblOrderDatas
                                    Join u In dc.tblUsers On u.UserNo Equals od.RecdBy
                                    Join pr In dc.tblProductss On pr.ProductRef Equals od.ProductRef
                                    Where od.ProductRef.StartsWith(tb_FIRefFind.Text.Trim()) And od.DateProcessed.HasValue = False
                                    Select New With {.ID = od.ID,
                                                     .DateReceived = od.DateRecd,
                                                     .ReceivedBy = u.FullName,
                                                     .OrderID = od.OrderID,
                                                     .ProductType = pr.ProductType,
                                                     .ProductRef = od.ProductRef,
                                                     .ProductName = pr.ProductName,
                                                     .ProductCat = pr.ProductCat,
                                                     .Qty = od.Qty})



;WITH tblUsers(UserNo, FullName) AS (SELECT UserNo, FullName FROM tblUsers) 
SELECT ID, DateRecd, N1.FullName As RecdBy, OrderID, c.ProductType a.ProductRef, 
c.ProdName, c.ProdCat, Qty, DateProcessed, N2.Fullname As ProcessedBy 
FROM tblOrderData As a JOIN tblUsers N1 ON a.RecdBy = N1.UserNo 
JOIN tblUsers N2 ON a.ProcessedBy = N2.UserNo 
JOIN tblProducts As c ON a.ProductRef = c.ProductRef 
WHERE a.ProductRef LIKE '" & tb_ProdRefFind.Text.Trim() & "%' 
AND DateProcessed Is Not Null
```

The first I've converted and its fine... the second where the full name of the user is extracted twice for the person that took the order and the one that processed it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Don't. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL, and you just found one case where it's infinitely better to use SQL rather than LINQ. ORMs in general are used to map entities to tables/views/statements. It's a very strong smell when you have to join multiple entities just to get a single entity in response

Comment: More issues: Applying functions is dangerous. If Linq2SQL can't convert a statement to SQL, it will pull in as much data as it can, then proceed to process the rest of the query in memory.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks... I think I know what you mean... I've spent a while trying... When I looked at the project I saw I would need to at least change the SQL to Parameterised values and thought I would use Linq also as I'm introducing Order class etc.

Comment: Two more issues: 1) Instead of joins you should add the proper relations between Users, Products, Order data etc. This would allow you to use eg `User.Orders` for a specific user. 2) Your query doesn't return an entity at all, it's a reporting query. It's better to create the proper view in the database then map to it

Comment: so scripts meant string concatenations? Ouch! L2S or EF aren't bad choices when you work with entities. Reporting queries though aren't entities, they are just shaped data. It's easier to do those in SQL statements, hidden behind views

Comment: Thats a good thought... I could create a view.... This may well solve my issue(s) as there are other example of this type of query.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Many thanks for advice. I have gone down the route of views for these reporting queries.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know this has been a while but if you'd like to answer this with the suggestion to use view I can give you credit as that's exactly what I did... Thanks